# How to create a child menu in a different place in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu

I have a main menu and it has a dropdown submenu. I also have to show the same submenu below main menu along with the dropdown and it will be always there. Please see the picture to get an overview.

I was thinking of using the page_id in each page and get children of that page and show them as that submenu. But problem arises when I am inside a child page. Then I cant get the children because the page_id is different. This also causes a problem for blog. Is there any best way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this in two ways:

- With the help of jQuery you can get the child menu and populate that
  child menu in desired `div` (i.e below the main menu)
- Even if you are in child page you can get the parent page id and
  selects his child page again with some checks.

jQuery is simple solution in my opinion. Example is given below.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6vu1nzu6/1/)

Comment: Yeah, jquery can do and its an easy solution. I think I will go for this. But This is a common problem. I was looking for some robust wordpress or PHP solution. Anyway thanks for your answer...

Answer (score 0):

Please check these lines.

```
<?php

global $post;     // if outside the loop

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
    // This is a subpage

} else {
    // This is not a subpage
}
?>
```